# Detect <embed> tag failing to load video

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, video-streaming, embed

I am trying to catch an error with the following embed tag (on iPad/iOS):

```
<embed width="320" height="240" 
  src="path/to/my/live/stream/playlist.m3u8"
  type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" postdomevents="true" id="movie1" />
```

I tried to catch it with the following:

```
$("#movie1").on('onerror', function() { alert('error!') } );
```

I also tried with `onabort`, `onstalled`, `onended`, and `onsuspend` - all not generating an event when the video fails to load.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can't use this argument with .on() instead use the raw writing `$("#movie1")[0].onerror = ...`

Comment: @Oddant: that does not seem to work, either.

Comment: did you try `$("#movie1").error(...)` ?

Comment: Found any luck with it? I am trying the same.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make a separate HTTP request to check the validity of the file path.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', 'http://path/to/your/video', false);
http.send();

if (http.status == 404) {
    throw new Error('Unable to load file')
} else {
    // Generate your <embed> tag here
}
```