# Eventhandler for <object> that fires if data does not exist

Tags: javascript, svg, event-handling, object-tag

I am loading SVG images with help of object tags into my page. I determine if an image is completly loaded by an `eventhandler` added to the object tags

```
objectTag.onload = initialiseSVG;
objectTag.onerror = handleError;
```

But if the SVG file does not exist the error function does not get called.

What is the correct way to check if the `<object>` data source is not available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366867/object-tag-doesnt-refresh-when-its-data-attribute-is-changed-in-chrome

Comment: i will have a look thank you

Comment: the link tells about a google chrome specific bug, in my case its not working with firefox and IE11, too. I also dont change the data source. I just cant find any handler which fires if the data source is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for longer on this problem and finally found a solution in another thread : 
[Detect <embed> tag failing to load video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490529/detect-embed-tag-failing-to-load-video) 
the answer from Evgueni was what i was looking for. With a `XMLHttpRequest` it is possible to check if an URL exists and so check if the data source is available before actually creating the object tag to include the data. Thanks for that unfortunately i have still to few reps to vote him up.